# How to auto highlight the current word in vim?

Tags: vim, highlight

For example, our text is:

```
hello world
abcd hello world
hello world
```

In eclipse, when your cursor is at some word, the word `hello` is auto highlight in the current file. When you type `ww` in normal mode, the cursor is at other word `world` will highlight in the current file, the `hello` is un-highlighted automatically. This feature is very convenient for users.

Does vim can do this with some plugin or else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a script on [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip572) for doing exactly that. It waits until you've stopped moving the cursor and then highlights all instances of the current word. You can then use `n` and `N` to jump between them like you normally would with search results.

I'm copying it here in case the link goes down:

```
" Highlight all instances of word under cursor, when idle.
" Useful when studying strange source code.
" Type z/ to toggle highlighting on/off.
nnoremap z/ :if AutoHighlightToggle()<Bar>set hls<Bar>endif<CR>
function! AutoHighlightToggle()
    let @/ = ''
    if exists('#auto_highlight')
        au! auto_highlight
        augroup! auto_highlight
        setl updatetime=4000
        echo 'Highlight current word: off'
        return 0
    else
        augroup auto_highlight
            au!
            au CursorHold * let @/ = '\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'
        augroup end
        setl updatetime=500
        echo 'Highlight current word: ON'
        return 1
    endif
endfunction
```

As noted in a comment on that page, if you always want this feature on you can just call the function from your `vimrc` after defining it. That way you can use `z/` (or whatever shortcut you assign it to) to turn it off again later.

Comment: Worked! Although have some minor bug. Can it change the highlight color?

Comment: I think it uses whatever color you've got set as `IncSearch`. See `:h hl-IncSearch` for help.

Comment: It works as a function, but cannot make is autostart. If it is called as a function from .vimrc, it prints the ON message, but it doesn't work. Same with using only the 'guts'.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this?

```
set updatetime=10

function! HighlightWordUnderCursor()
    if getline(".")[col(".")-1] !~# '[[:punct:][:blank:]]' 
        exec 'match' 'Search' '/\V\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>/' 
    else 
        match none 
    endif
endfunction

autocmd! CursorHold,CursorHoldI * call HighlightWordUnderCursor()
```

This won't clobber the search register but will use the same highlighting as would normally be used. (If you want a different highlight color change `Search` to that highlight group.) A short update time is needed so that the CursorHold event it fired fairly often. It also won't highlight anything if the cursor is above punctuation or whitespace.

The `iskeyword` setting determines what is considered part of a word when `expand('<cword>')` is used.

Comment: This is fantastic because it doesn't clobber the search register!

Comment: Could you be more specific about how to make the color different from the search highlight?

Comment: wow, it works perfectly, a few lines of vimscript code can be life changes

Comment: @lsimmons type `:highlight` to find all the different highlight group names. (its the first column). Replace the word `'Search'` above the the new highlight group name 
Example: `:s/Search/ErrorMsg`

Answer (score 5):

Improving @FDinoff's amazing answer, with custom highlight - dark BG and underline, and disable on quickfix list, fugitive filetype and when on diff:

```
function! HighlightWordUnderCursor()
    let disabled_ft = ["qf", "fugitive", "nerdtree", "gundo", "diff", "fzf", "floaterm"]
    if &diff || &buftype == "terminal" || index(disabled_ft, &filetype) >= 0
        return
    endif
    if getline(".")[col(".")-1] !~# '[[:punct:][:blank:]]'
        hi MatchWord cterm=undercurl gui=undercurl guibg=#3b404a
        exec 'match' 'MatchWord' '/\V\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>/'
    else
        match none
    endif
endfunction

augroup MatchWord
  autocmd!
  autocmd! CursorHold,CursorHoldI * call HighlightWordUnderCursor()
augroup END
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a vim plugin for highlighting the occurances of a word automatically. This [one](https://bitbucket.org/sras/vawa) is implemented exclusively for `$variables` and `->properties` in **.php** files.

**DEMO :**
[image]

And [here](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2014/05/automatic-variable-highlighting-in-vim.html) is the same one but adapted for **Perl** files.

**DEMO :**

[image]

May be you can modify it for your purpose.

Comment: @jinleileiking if you like the plugin, you could try to change this line https://bitbucket.org/sras/vawa/src/303c32f257113115ed724018ed13f229d7a6759c/plugin/vawa.vim?at=default#cl-80 and line#81    `*.php -> *`

Comment: @Kent I don't think changing that line (line#81) will change anything. The script highlights only `$variable` and `->properties`. So it will highlight only words begining with `$` and `->`.

Comment: @blackbishop oh, sorry, I didn't check what the plugin does. then OP need check and chg the regex.